# Regex to match full lines of text excluding crlf

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How would a regex pattern to match each line of a given text be?

I'm trying `^(.+)$` but it includes crlf...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "match each line of a given text" means, but you can use a character class to exclude the CR and LF characters:

```
[^\r\n]+
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use [RegexOptions.Multiline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx).

> Multiline mode. Changes the meaning of
>   ^ and $ so they match at the beginning
>   and end, respectively, of any line,
>   and not just the beginning and end of
>   the entire string.

Example:

```
var lineMatches = Regex.Matches("Multi\r\nlines", "^(.+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your question seems a little unclear, but it sounds like you want [`RegexOptions.Multiline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) (in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace). It's an option you have to set on your RegEx object. That should make `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a *line* rather than the entire string.

For example:

```
Regex re = new Regex("^(.+)$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
^(.+)\r?\n$
```

That way the match group includes everything except the CRLF, and requires that a new line be present (Unix default), but accepts the carriage return in front (Windows default).

Comment: ^(.+?)\r?\n$ or it greedily eats the \r (.+ == greedy, .+? == non-greedy)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the Multiline option?  In that case you'll want to match the newline explicitly with "\n".  (substitute "\r\n" as appropriate.)